# Passwords can’t contain the user name or parts of the user’s full name in oracle database(pl/sq)

Tags: oracle, plsql

Actually, I have a little problem is I am working on app having in which a form to register user and on validation end password must not contain user's name, and must not contains consecutive 2 letters form user's name.
The client requirement is to do this through Stored Procedure.
e.g., “zia123” is not an appropriate password for user “Zia”

Any one have idea about this PL?SQL Stored Procedure function?

Comment: @B001ᛦ Perhaps OP is a contractor for an IT portion of a large company, in which case OP should definitely be taking technical requirements from their client. If you believe this is an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) then please state that instead.

Comment: The "Two consecutive letters" requirement feels like it might best be solved using a 2-gram (n-gram) comparison. There is no built in function in Oracle though, so you'll have to roll your own. Also, it does feel odd to be doing this in a procedure instead of the application where functionality like this would surely be supported regardless of the language.

Comment: So password like `YoM4QG./SsJE3<n&pzihpjW(Sbm<-3xaNKExc2gc,&u&@J<,+&FtVS*u8vvUF` you would not consider as appropriate (because it contains `zi`)? You will make your users really nasty if they have rather long user user names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try looking at the provided Oracle password verification functions for assistance in writing this sort of thing - `ora12c_verify_function` and `ora12c_strong_verify_function` on 12c. I'm including an `old_password` parameter here because a common requirement with password verification is comparing the new password to the old one.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function verify_password_complexity
    (username varchar2,
     password varchar2,
     old_password varchar2)
return varchar2 IS
begin

   -- password must not contain user's name. 
   -- They didn't specify but I'm assuming their requirements want a case-insensitive check.
   if (upper(password) like '%' || upper(username) || '%') then
      return 'password contains username';
   end if;

   -- must not contains consecutive 2 letters from user's name
   for u in (select substr(username,level,2) as pair -- get all pairs of letters
                from dual
                connect by level <= length(username)-1)
   loop
      -- does password contain this pair
      if (upper(password) like '%' || upper(u.pair) || '%') then
        return 'password contains 2 consecutive letters from username: ' || u.pair;
      end if;
   end loop;

   return 'password OK';

end;
/
```

Testing:

```
begin
  dbms_output.put_line(verify_password_complexity('testuser', 'lkajsdofiuwe', 'oiuwlkajsdf'));
  dbms_output.put_line(verify_password_complexity('testuser', 'lkajsdofiuwer', 'oiuwlkajsdf'));
  dbms_output.put_line(verify_password_complexity('testuser', 'lkatestuseruwe', 'oiuwlkajsdf'));
end;
/

password OK
password contains 2 consecutive letters from username: er
password contains username
```

Comment: Thank you soo much for sorting out my issue.

Answer (score 2):

For example, a function:

```
SQL> create or replace function f_unpw (par_username in varchar2, par_password in varchar2)
  2    return varchar2
  3  is
  4    l_username varchar2(30)  := upper(par_username);
  5    l_password varchar2(30)  := upper(par_password);
  6    retval     varchar2(200) := 'Password is OK';
  7  begin
  8    if instr(l_password, l_username) > 0 or
  9       regexp_like(l_password, '[[:alpha:]]{2,}')
 10    then
 11       retval := 'Password contains username or two (or more) consecutive letters';
 12    end if;
 13
 14    return retval;
 15  end;
 16  /

Function created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> with test (un, pw) as
  2    (select 'zIA' , 'zia123' from dual union all
  3     select 'LF'  , 'x123bh' from dual union all
  4     select 'Test', '334d'   from dual
  5    )
  6  select un,
  7         pw,
  8         f_unpw(un, pw) result
  9  from test;

UN   PW     RESULT
---- ------ ----------------------------------------------------------------------
zIA  zia123 Password contains username or two (or more) consecutive letters
LF   x123bh Password contains username or two (or more) consecutive letters
Test 334d   Password is OK

SQL>
```

Feel free to enhance it.

Comment: Your answer is great, it's really really helps me, but it doesn't receive more then character(Alphabets)